# orderBy on value in object with ui-typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to orderBy major in the following list of objects with my ui-typeahead input.

```
[
    {
        name: 'London (LHR)',
        code: 'LHR',
        country: 'GB',
        major: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Gatwick (LGW)',
        code: 'LGW',
        country: 'GB',
        major: 0
    }
]

<input 
    type="text" 
    name="destination" 
    uib-typeahead="airport as airport.name for airport in getAirports($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | orderBy:airport.major | limitTo:8" 
/>
```

I tried "major" and "airport.major" as in the above example. Major essentially reflects if an airport is a big one. For example London Heathrow would be a 1, while Gatwick would be a 0.

getAirports() creates my Airports object as the output needs some validation on the airport names.

orderBy has no effect, can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me was putting the value on which I wanted to sort in single quotes. So based on your example this would be:

```
 <input type="text" name="destination" 
    uib-typeahead="airport.name for airport in getAirports($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | orderBy:'major' | limitTo:8" 
/>
```